# Equation of a natural spline vs just a spline

Tags: splines

A spline of order $r$ (with $K$ knots) can be written as:

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{r-1}\beta_i x^{i} + \sum_{j=1}^K b_j(x-\kappa_{j})^{r-1}_+$$

A natural spline is defined as a spline that has order $2r$ inside $\left[ x_{(1)}, x_{(n)} \right]$, and is a polynomial of order $r$ outside of $\left[ x_{(1)}, x_{(n)} \right]$.

But what does the equation for a natural spline look like? If we take:
$$f_{\texttt{natural}}(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{r-1}\beta_i x^{i} + \sum_{j=1}^K b_j(x-\kappa_{j})^{2r-1}_+,$$
then this satisfies first extra condition to be a natural spline, however it only satisfies the second extra condition on $(-\infty, x_{(1)})$. I do not know how to "turn off" the $(x-\kappa_j)_+$ terms on $(x_{(n)}, \infty)$, they are a polynomial of order $2r$ there.